# Physical interaction between objects

Tags: physics

Is it possible with Blender to have a physical interaction (dealing with contacts) between objects?

For example:

- I would like to make a sphere scratch another object and imprint a permanent plastic deformation on this object.
- I would like a sphere enter inside a cylindrical part (with an elastic behavior) and expand it from the inside.

Is it possible to do this with Blender, or by combining Blender with external tools?

Comment: I believe what you want to look at is *dynamic paint*.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Blender is absolutely capable of doing this.  The feature you are looking for is called *dynamic paint*.

[image]

To do this simply select the object you want to deform, go to the *physics* tab, click on *dynamic paint*, and choose *canvas*.

[image]

Then just scroll down to the *dynamic paint advanced* rollout and choose *displace* under *surface type*.

[image]

Next, select the object you want to use to inflict the deformation and set it as a dynamic paint brush (just select *brush* instead of *canvas*).

Then you can animate the brush object to scratch across the canvas object and it will deform it.

A few tips for using dynamic paint:

- You will want the canvas object to have plenty of subdivisions so that it has enough geometry to get deformed.
- You may want to enable *anti-aliasing* and add some *sub-steps* on the canvas object for a smoother deformation, particularly if the brush object is moving fast.  This makes Blender sample the motion of the object between frames for smoother painting.
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easly achieve physically believable results by running physic simulation, dynamic paint, keyframed shape keys, molecular add-on, fluids... a mix of all... but remember that Blender is an animation-focused software, so don't expect to be asked just about some real world phisical parameters and let the software do all the work.

*First example:*

An interesting way to imprint plastic deformation by using a "static" cloth simulation can bee seen in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=267&v=wJFE2pb0Ri4

The object to be deformed is a highliy subdivided, cloth physic enabled, with structural stiffnes set to 0 in order to keep the deformation caused by a second object that has collision physic enabled.

*Second example:*

No smart idea about.
Maybe a fluid simulation (if I have well understood what is your concept about). The cilinder act as a boundary and the sphere emit big fluid particles in both direction...but the interface will never be smooth as an expanding sphere has.