# How do I make the upholstry of a vehicle panel looked puckered by a door handle?

Tags: modifiers, objects

Simples. 
I just want to create a depression in the panel, as if it was made of leather and the door handle was installed against it. 
[image]

Here's the best example I could find. Note how the panel around the hardware with the red thing hanging out has caused a depression.  I tried to create more loops and add an inset area on the panel, but that caused the panel to act weird due to my subsurf modifier. I'm hoping there is some deform that will "push in" based on another object
[image]

Comment: see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33932/physical-interaction-between-objects

Comment: Dynamic paint with brush=door handle using proximity and canvas=panel as displacement?

Comment: Hmm, I need to find a better picture, the surface bulges out as a result of the displacement

Comment: somewhat related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/model-upholstery-with-buttons

Answer (score 3):

As example, my monkey is the door handle, and my cube is the door panel.

- Use for both a subsurf modifier.
- Overlap the monkey with the cube
- Enable the cube as canvas and set type to displacement
  [image]
- Enable the monkey as brush and set paint source to mesh volume
  [image]