# How an animated object moving on a plane could leave a mark on it?

Tags: animation, objects

I want to know how an animated object moving on a plane could leave a mark on it.

In the exact way shown in this video
https://youtu.be/cUsXyimUw6o?t=97
from 1:37 to 1:45

I need to explain how a cleaner product cleans the floor.

I want to show the area where the machine is cleaning.

I want to mark the floor where the machine passed through.

**How I can do it?**

In post-production for sure, but if possible (and if it's convenient) I want to avoid other softwares. I would do it on Blender.

Thanks

Comment: you probably need to look into the Dynamic Paint modifier

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33932 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66417